# using SQL to detect sex change

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset like this:

- id : E.g. 111, 111, 111, 112, 112, 113, 113
- Year: E.g. 2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011,2010, 2015
- Sex: E.g. M, M, F, F, F, M, M

In this dataset, ID = 111 had a sex change (switch from M to F - or from F to M)

With postgre sql, I try to find out:

- A: How many ids stay as man (and which ids)
- B: How many ids stay as woman (and which ids)
- C: How many ids go from man to woman (and which ids)
- D: How many ids go from woman to man (and which ids)

I try like this:

```
# problem A
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'M');
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'M');

# problem B
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'F');
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'F');

# all sex change
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'M') AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'F');
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'M') AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE SEX = 'F');
```

Is it correct? Or is window-lag function needed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, to calculate in advance some metrics:

```
 SELECT *
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS has_M
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS has_F
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, year) AS initial_sex
  FROM mytable;
```

[image]

and then solve your issues:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      ,string_agg(CASE WHEN initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'M' THEN CAST(id AS VARCHAR(12)) END, ', ') 
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      ,string_agg(CASE WHEN initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'F' THEN CAST(id AS VARCHAR(12)) END, ', ') 
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN (initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'F' AND has_m = 1) OR (initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'M' AND has_F = 1)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      ,string_agg(CASE WHEN (initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'F' AND has_m = 1) OR (initial_sex = 1 AND SEX = 'M' AND has_F = 1)  THEN CAST(id AS VARCHAR(12)) END, ', ') 
FROM
(
  SELECT *
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS has_M
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS has_F
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, year) AS initial_sex
  FROM mytable
) DS;
```

[image]

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/59b103/19) is the full working example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column SEX will only have either 'F' or 'M' as value, problem A can be solved

problem A

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table WHERE  SEX != 'F';
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM table WHERE  SEX != 'F';
```

Answer (score 0):

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SuaQtkcx)

Assuming, the change happens only once, you could use the [`first_value()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT                                                                   -- 5
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN first_sex = last_sex THEN 'Stay ' || sex                             -- 3
        ELSE 'Change from ' || first_sex || ' To ' || last_sex                    -- 4    
    END sex_status
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        sex,
        first_value(sex) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year) as first_sex,       -- 1
        first_value(sex) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY year DESC) as last_sex    -- 2
    FROM mytable
) s
```

1. Fetch first `sex` values per `id` over `year`s
2. Fetch last `sex` values per `id` over `year`s (Notice the different order: It gives the first value from the "bottom")
3. Compare first and last; if they are the same, return "Stay" and sex
4. Otherwise return "Change" with sexes. (Of course, you can do whatever you want here. Adding appropriate status identifiers or similar instead of pure text seems to make sense at this point.)
5. `DISTINCT` clause to reduce the records to one per `id`.

---

Afterwards you can do whatever statistics you want. For example counting the different status by `GROUP BY sex_status`:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-x1kPTGp)

```
SELECT 
    sex_status,
    COUNT(*)
FROM (

-- query from above

) s
GROUP BY sex_status
```